# Creating multiply instances of a Facebook Messenger bot programmatically?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Got an interesting requirement from a client which goes as follows:

To create a new platform for their clients to be able to create surveys and capture feedback via Facebook Messenger.

All participants in the survey have given their consent. A participant can then have a two-way "chat" with the bot to answer the survey questions.

The above seems fairly straightforward after you have created a Facebook app, facebook page, created a messenger bot (associated to new page) and got that approved etc manually.

However, I want to be able to do all of this via the API so my platform can do it all programmatically. I'm currently exploring the Facebook Graph API and Twilio.

The other complexity I have is that a client might want to create multiple bots for different surveys so a participant might actually be answering two surveys for the same client and a survey another client but in three different "bot" chats.

Anyone else ever done something like this before? Also trying with WhatsApp but every platform like Twilio, MessageBird are all in early access beta with WhatsApp reviewing all requests so no idea how long that will take to get approved.

Comment: you cannot create apps with the api, that would be weird. you would still have to go through review with all apps too. try putting all that stuff into one bot only.

Comment: Apologies, meant to say the Facebook app would already be set up and approved. It’s the other parts. Putting it all into one bot won’t work as each client will potentially have different participants answering different surveys and need a way of knowing who has answered what and what it relates to which you wouldn’t be able to do in one bot. Carving it up into a bot per page helps a bit but there is still the issue of surveys per bot per client.